# In Supernatural, why is a certain entity still evil?

Tags: supernatural

In Supernatural Season 11 episode 8 when

> Sam is back in the cage with Lucifer,

why is the latter still evil?
We have seen earlier that the reason for his evilness <strike>is</strike> may be

> that he was the first bearer of the Mark  of Cain (the result of God betraying the Darkness) and the Mark is supposed to corrupt the bearer.

But since the

> Mark

has been destroyed and Dean is back to normal, why doesn't the same happen to

> Lucifer. Why is he still evil?

Comment: It's not implied that the only reason Lucifer is evil is because of the mark. While at first it may be that that started it all, I would find it hard to believe that being locked up in a cage would be easy to digest to one of the top-5 strongest beings in the Supernatural World

Answer (score 2):

This is discussed in the season 11 episode "We Happy Few". It's notable that Lucifer expresses a similar opinion to the one in the question, that he was corrupted by the Mark. However, a different source gives a different perspective:

> **Lucifer:** [God] gave me the Mark to lock [the Darkness] away and when it changed me, when it did what the Mark inevitably does, [He] threw me away.
>
> **Chuck:** No *[...]* The Mark didn't change you, it just made you more of what you already were.
>
> <sup>*Supernatural* Season 11 Episode 22: "We Happy Few"</sup>

Considering what we know about Chuck,

> Namely, that he is God

It seems wise to take him at his word here.

Comment: Chuck doesn't seem as omniscient as we perceive God to be. For instance, his first draft of his book God: An Autobiography seemed like complete rubbish, and Metatron managed to put him in his place (with words) several times that episode. Also, Chuck said some things that were outright wrong, e.g. when he told Dean he planned to let Amara imprison him, he reassured him that humanity could maybe rally against her (if he wanted to wipe out humans, would they stand a chance? I think not). Also, ...

Comment: in the finale, he tells Dean Earth has him to protect it, but we shouldn't forget how Dean's been lucky on a  number of occasions (e.g. the apocalypse and impala). So in supernatural, I don't think God's word is enough on any matter

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so here's my theory: (SPOILERS)
When God gave Lucifer the Mark, it corrupted him. Then he passed it on to Cain, but Lucifer stayed evil. I'd like to think that even if you pass on the Mark, then some of the evil residue stays with you. This is supported by the fact that Cain went on that killing spree even after passing the Mark to Dean Winchester.
So why didn't Dean stay corrupted after he got rid of the Mark of Cain? I personally think it's because he didn't pass on the Mark to someone else like Lucifer and Cain did. He actually destroyed it with the spell. Since the Mark was absolutely decimated, all of its evil was washed away from Dean, too. The only byproduct was the Darkness being released.